# How can i list current author's categories?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, categories, list-authors, codex

My Code getting authors written post categories but just 2 ID has author lists category.. I replace `$current_user->ID` but it is not worked.

```
<?php
    $categories = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT DISTINCT(terms.term_id) as ID, terms.name, terms.slug
        FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as relationships ON posts.ID = relationships.object_ID
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as tax ON relationships.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as terms ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id
        WHERE 1=1 AND (
            posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
            posts.post_author = '2' AND
            tax.taxonomy = 'category' )
        ORDER BY terms.name ASC
    ");
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($categories as $category) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $category->name ?>"><?php echo $category->name ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this...

you need to first call `global $post;`

then get the author id like `$author_id = $post->post_author;`

Comment: I have a question again. I used this code in sidebar.php its worked perfectly but when i use thats code with sidebar php widget.( My plugin 'exec-php' )  

i see error : 'Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in http://website.com\wp-content\plugins\exec-php\includes\runtime.php(42) : eval()'d code on line 3' 
and runtime.php 42 line have this code: eval("?>$content<?php ");
How can i use it in my php widget. I changed code a little it [here](http://pastebin.com/kQSnR739)

Comment: try adding `global $wpdb;`

Comment: that would then be `global $post, $wpdb;`