# Publish Categories for a particular Author on a given Post

Tags: loop, categories

Suppose I have this HTML →

```
 <div class="author-category">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">CATEGORY 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">CATEGORY 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">CATEGORY 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">CATEGORY 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="">CATEGORY 5</a></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

I tried this code, but this is code is not able to pull any categories →

`<ul>
            <?php foreach($categories as $category) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $category->name ?>"><?php echo $category->name ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>`

Now I want to run a loop so that I can fetch categories, but the constraint is that the categories should be fetched only for the author of that Post.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81599/how-can-i-list-current-authors-categories

Comment: With the help of that post I can pull categories, but how can we put restraint of an author. I mean I just want to pull categories for that post only.

Comment: Sure, but now you've changed what your original question stated. :-). Please update your question and add the code your're working with.

Comment: Sir, I have updated and done that.

Comment: You'll need to use the code from the answer I linked to.

Comment: Just copy pasted that not working. Any alternative code or any refined version that you can create sir, and help me?

Comment: I modified the code with the help of this article and it worked → http://martyspellerberg.com/2011/10/creating-a-wordpress-categories-page/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58536/discussion-between-the-wp-novice-and-dave-romsey).